# Existing .rb files to create local MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rubymine

I downloaded source code from BitBucket and I am trying to set up a local MySQL database with an existing .rb files in RubyMine. Is there a direct way to do so or do I need to set up all the tables manually?

Comment: If you have `seeds.rb` you can run `rake db:seed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the database for a Rails project in one command:

```
$ rails db:create
```

*(for Rails 5 only; if you're using Rails <= 4, `s/rails/rake/`)*

You'll also need to load the schema in, which is one more command:

```
$ rails db:schema:load
```

If you have seeding data in `seeds.rb`, you can load that with one further command:

```
$ rails db:seed
```